# Tree Diagrams Probability stock %

Tags: probability

A shop stocks tinned cat food of two makes, A and B, and two sizes, large and small. Of the stock, 70%
is of brand A, 30% is of the brand B. Of the tins of brand A, 30% are of the small size, whilst of the tins
of brand B, 40% are of the small size. Determine the probability that
(a) a tin chosen at random from the stock will be of the small size.
(b) a small tin chosen at random from the stock will be brand A.

(a) Easy working answer: 0.33

(b) using 0.7x 0.3=0.21 but the answer is 7/11
How to tackle with it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is incomplete as you only found out the probability of the chosen box being a small tin of type A, whereas you need to determine *whether* the box is of type A, *given* that it is a small tin.

The right way to do this would be to essentially use *Bayes Theorem*, since you already know that you have a small tin and now need to determine which type it is. The required probability is given by,

P(S ∩ A) / ((P(S ∩ A) + P(S ∩ B)) = 7/11